# Magento 2 : CLI Commands are not working with Magento 2.4.2 after uprade php version to PHP 8

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

Working on Magento upgrade from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4. but somehow commands are not working after upgrading the PHP version to PHP 8.1.

Please suggest some solution for the same.

Comment: Do have more information? Do you get any errors or something? Can you share screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.2 is not compatible with PHP 8.
So, this is the expected result.
I recommend you update to 2.4.4 version with is compatible with PHP 8